# Packing 20 bytes chunk via BLE

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, communication, chunks

I've never worked with bluetooth before. I have to sends data via BLE and I've found the limit of 20 bytes per chunk.

The sender is an Arduino and the receiver could be both an Android or a Node.js app on a pc.

I have to send 9 values, stored in float values, so 4 bytes * 9 = 36 bytes. I need 2 chunks for all my data via BLE. The receiving part needs both chunks to process them. If some data are lost, I don't care.

I'm not expert in network protocols and I think I have to give each message an incremental timestamp so that the receiver can glue the two chunks with the same timestamp or discard the last one if the new timestamp is higher. But I'm not sure how to do a checksum, if I really need it or not, if I really have to care about it, or if - for a simple beta version of my system - I can ignore all those problems..

Does anyone can give me some advice? Like examples of similar situations handled with BLE communication?

Comment: BLE differs from classical Bluetooth in many ways, since the you cannot assign the two devices as "sender" and "receiver". You need to understand the basic principle of the Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) in BLE, which defines how to access a service from a GATT Server using a Gatt Client, which is based on UUIDs.

Comment: @OsmanEsen: can you be a little bit more clear please? You're right that the BLE differs from normal bluetooth but I need to connect to one device at a time.. do you mean that with different profile I can send more then 20 bytes?

Comment: No. I have worked a lot with BLE devices from Texas Instruments, which all have a limit of 20 bytes as well. This limit is a common limit for BLE, so you won't be able to send more than 20 bytes at a time.

Comment: @OsmanEsen so what does GATT can be useful? berating a new characteristic and notify the client of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the size limitation using the "Read Blob Request" of ATT.  It allows you to read an attribute and also give an offset.  So, you can use it to read the attribute with an offset of 0, if there's more than ATT_MTU bytes than you can request again with the offset at ATT_MTU*1, if there's still more ATT_MTU*2, etc...  (You can read it in 3.4.4.5 of the Bluetooth v4.1 specifications; it's in the 4.0 spec too but I don't have that in front of me right now)

If the value changes between request, I'm not sure how you could go about detecting such a change.  You could have the attribute send notifications when there's a change to interrupt the process in case the value changes in the middle of reading it.

Comment: uao. this answer is very precise.. more then I can fully understand probably.. do you have any idea on how to do it with Nordic Semicondutor SDK for Arduino?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I haven't used that before.  You could try searching their docs for "blob".